# tensorflow: output layer with a single neuron, expected float output [0.0,1.0]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to build a nn with an output layer consisting of a single neuron only. My input data contain 500 floats assigned to a "0" or "1". The final nn should output a "probability" value [0.0, 1.0].
Since I'm new to tensorflow, I have taken an MNIST example from Aurélien Géron's excellent book and modified it according to my needs. However, I'm stuck at a few points. Basically, he uses a "softmax" function at some point, which can't be correct for my example. Also, his evaluation function ("tf.nn.in_top_k") can't be right. Finally, I'm wondering if I need an activation function for the output layer ("sigmoid"?).
Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n_inputs = 500

n_hidden1 = 400
n_hidden2 = 300

n_outputs = 1


# import training, test and validation data...
X_train,y_train = <import my training data as "np.array" objects>
X_valid,y_valid = <import my validation data as "np.array" objects>
X_test,y_test   = <import my testing data as "np.array" objects>


seed    = 42
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name="y")

def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.get_shape()[1])
        stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(n_inputs)
        init = tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddev)
        W = tf.Variable(init, name="kernel")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name="bias")
        Z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
        if activation is not None:
            return activation(Z)
        else:
            return Z

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1",activation=tf.nn.relu)
    hidden2 = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2",activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # do I need an activation function here?
    logits = neuron_layer(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")


with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    # this is probably not correct - I should most likely use something like "sigmoid"... but how exactly do I do that?
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

learning_rate = 0.01

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)


with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    # same thing here. what is the right function to be used here?
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

n_epochs = 100
batch_size = 50

def shuffle_batch(X, y, batch_size):
    rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
    n_batches = len(X) // batch_size
    for batch_idx in np.array_split(rnd_idx, n_batches):
        X_batch, y_batch = X[batch_idx], y[batch_idx]
        yield X_batch, y_batch

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for X_batch, y_batch in shuffle_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size):
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_batch = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_valid, y: y_valid})
        print(epoch, "Batch accuracy:", acc_batch, "Val accuracy:", acc_val)

    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")
```

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Thanks a lot for your reply. Introducing the "sigmoid" function was a step in the right direction. But, there are still some problems:

1.) When training the nn the accuracy is not very good:

```
(95, 'Batch accuracy:', 0.54, 'Val accuracy:', 0.558)
(96, 'Batch accuracy:', 0.52, 'Val accuracy:', 0.558)
(97, 'Batch accuracy:', 0.56, 'Val accuracy:', 0.558)
(98, 'Batch accuracy:', 0.58, 'Val accuracy:', 0.558)
(99, 'Batch accuracy:', 0.52, 'Val accuracy:', 0.558)
```

2.) It seems as if the returned results when testing the trained model are too low. The values are all between [0.0,0.3]:

```
('Predicted classes:', array([[0.2000685 ],[0.17176622],[0.14039296],[0.15600625],[0.15928227],[0.15543781],[0.1348885 ],[0.17185831],[0.170376],[0.17732298],[0.17864114],[0.16391528],[0.18579942],[0.12997991],[0.13886571],[0.24408364],       [0.17308617],[0.16365634],[0.1782803 ],[0.11332873]], dtype=float32))
('Actual classes:   ', array([0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,1., 0., 0.]))
```

I guess, my validation function still isn't right:

```
with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    predicted = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.round(predicted), y)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

How must a correct validation function look like?

Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Just use any activation function bounded between 0 and 1 (sigmoid is one of them)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an easy solution using keras - seems to be much more intuitive to use for beginners in my opinion. Found' this on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T91fsaG2L0s):

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy

import sys

filename    = sys.argv[1]

# fix random
numpy.random.seed(42)

# loading data (roughly 500 input nodes per line)
dataset = numpy.loadtxt(filename)
print "Elems in file: ",len(dataset)
print "Elems per line: ",len(dataset[0])

n   = len(dataset[0])-1

# separate the last values of ech line into "y"
X = dataset[:,0:n]
y = dataset[:,n]

# split X, y into a train and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# create model, add dense layers one by one specifying activation function
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(800, input_dim=n, activation='relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # sigmoid for final probability between 0 and 1

# compile the model, adam gradient descent (optimized)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# training the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 1000, batch_size=50, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

# save the model
model.save("trained_test_model")

scores  = model.evaluate(X_train,y_train)
print model.metrics_names[1],scores[1]*100.0,"%%"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Logits should not have an activation.
2. Loss should be sigmoid capable of handling logits, `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is the one.
3. You can calculate accuracy by checking whether final logit is less than zero or more than zero. If the first case, classify it as 0, if second, classify as 1. I'm not sure whether there is a built-in in tf for this.